# Power Query compare value (string) in one column against set of headers of other columns

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a CSV with thousands of rows and 30+ columns. I am trying to compare:

- the **value** of each row of column AnimalType which I call $AnimalType[n];
- the column **headers** of four other columns, which I call ${"Header"&$Animaltype}
- matching values against column DateBegin, but only if that date is in the past 30 days.

In the very small number of cases where all three conditions are true, I need to replace any nulls with the value in DateBegin.

Possible values:

- $AnimalType[n] can be one of {"CAT", "DOG", null}. It is unlikely that there will be additional possible values of this column.
- `${"Header"&$(AnyThreeChars)&$Animaltype}` can be one of {"HeaderAaaCAT", "HeaderAaaDOG", "HeaderBbbCAT", "HeaderBbbDOG"} though this could expand to include several other pairs (e.g., HeaderQqqCAT & HeaderQqqDOG, HeaderEeeCAT & HeaderEeeDOG, HeaderDddCAT & HeaderDddDOG, et. al.)

```
IF (
    $HEADER = "Header"&${AnimalType[n]} ) 
         and ( Date.IsInPreviousNDays($DateBegin[n]),30 )
         and ( ${"Header"&${AnimalType[n]}[n]} = null )
    )
THEN set ${"Header"&${AnimalType[n]}[n]} = $DateBegin[n]
ELSE leave ${"Header"&${AnimalType[n]}[n]} unchanged
```

and then proceed check the rest of the values.
[image: Data as imported from CSV]
In my example data, I have three rows that match the conditions above:

- row  8: replace only the value under HeaderAaaDOG since the value under HeaderBbbDOG exists
- row 12: both CAT values are null, so replace them both
- row 24: both DOG values are null, so replace them both
  [image: Transformed data]

Apologies for the pics, but I couldn't access any file style from work yesterday afternoon.

Here's my data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZDh3nVMdwcrN5QOjiY5Vuy0pgUi92qaaFrDDCj8fWeY/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please don't post pictures. Supply sample data as copiable text along with expected output.

Comment: No one wants to retype all that to help you.  As for question, in Row 5, both DOG values are null. Why are they not changing like row 12 where explanation was "both CAT values are null, so replace them both"? Additionally, explain date logic with example showing where things would or would not change

Comment: @DavideBacci sorry, I've added data as a shared Google doc

Comment: @horseyride I've filled in all of the empty cells in the Desired Output tab with the reason they remain empty (i.e., which condition(s) they fail to meet). In the case of row 5, tarragon is older than 30d, so no change is made.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to produce your desired output.
The `Row.Transform` transformation list should be dynamic so you can add other column headers, and even other animals so long as they are characterised by having the last characters of the Headers being capitalized, preceded by a non-capitalized character (or digit) and identical to the animal name in the `AnimalType` column.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"AnimalType", type text}, 
        {"DateBegin", type date}, {"HeaderAaaDOG", type date}, 
        {"HeaderAaaCAT", type date}, {"HeaderBbbDOG", type date}, 
        {"HeaderBbbCAT", type date}}),

    animals = List.RemoveNulls(List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[AnimalType])),
    #"Last Caps" = List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), 
        (li)=> List.Last(Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"a".."z","0".."9"},{"A".."Z"})(li))),
    x = List.Transform(#"Last Caps", (li)=>List.Contains(animals,li)),
    #"Chk Cols" =List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),each x{List.PositionOf(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),_)}),
    
    #"Replace nulls" = 
        Table.TransformRows(#"Changed Type", (r)=>
            Record.TransformFields(r, 
            List.Buffer(    
                List.Transform(List.Transform(#"Chk Cols", 
                    each {_, List.Last(Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition(
                        {"a".."z","0".."9"},{"A".."Z"})(_))}),
                (li)=>
                    {li{0},  each 
                            if (Record.Field(r,"DateBegin") > Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),-30)??false)
                                and (Record.Field(r,li{0}) = null) 
                                and (Record.Field(r,"AnimalType") =li{1})
                                then Record.Field(r,"DateBegin")
                                else Record.Field(r,li{0})}
                )))),
                        
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Replace nulls", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Column Names" = Record.FieldNames(#"Replace nulls"{0}),

    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", #"Column Names"),
    #"Set Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1", {{"AnimalType", type text},{"DateBegin", type date}} & List.Transform(#"Chk Cols", each {_, type date}) )
in
    #"Set Types"
```

***Source***
[image]

***Results***
[image]